# redux: How to organized the reducers

Tags: react-native, redux, action

How do I organized my reducers if I have multiple similar reducers eg. loading profile, loading headlines....

I may have action name : LOADING_PROFILE, LOADING_PROFILE_SUCCESS and LOADING_PROFILE_FAILURE. For headlines, will have the same action names.

Is it possible to have those set merged into one set which become LOADING, LOADING_SUCCESS and LOADING_FAILURE.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic#customizing-behavior-with-higher-order-reducers

Answer (score 0):

If the loading flag is similar for all these components. It would make sens to use one reducer that control and update this flag. However, you may want to have separate loading indicators for different components for few reasons:

1. Lazy loading - each component will have its own loading indicator and it wont make sense for it to be dependent on other lazy loaded component.
2. Updating - each component has its own fields and should be dependently update itself. Therefore, using another flag for update is compelling in this case.
3. Fetching Data/API calls - component will want to show loading whether the data isn't available yet.

As applications scale, there could be many flags that can trigger the loading indicator for each of its component. Hence, It will be hard for you to merge them into a common reducer.